# importing Excel spreadsheets data into SQLiite database in my WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am trying to inport Excel spreadsheet data into a SQLite db in a WPF app(not a Form) using Xaml and C# but I can't seem to get the code to help me do it easily. Can anyone please help me with the code or tell me where I can find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to import the data from excel worksheet is by using a class with your data types of the spreadsheet.

```html
namespace ExcelToDatabase
{
    public class Columns
    {
        private string _column1;
        private int _column2;
        private int _column3;

        public string Column1 { get => _column1; set => _column1 = value; }
        public int Column2 { get => _column2; set => _column2 = value; }
        public int Column3 { get => _column3; set => _column3 = value; }
        
}
```

The data from excel can read row by row with EPPlus package.

```html
 public partial class readExcelFile : Form
    {
        public List<ExcelToDatabase.Columns> ColumnList = new List<ExcelToDatabase.Columns>();

        public readExcelFile()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void readData()
        {

            string FilePath = @"C:\excelsheet.xlsx";

            FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
            {

                //if there are more than one worksheet
                for (int x = 1; x <= package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count; x++)
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[x];
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count

                    for (int Row = 2; Row <= rowCount; Row++)
                    {
                        ExcelToDatabase.Columns Temp = new ExcelToDatabase.Columns();

                        Temp.Column1 = worksheet.Cells[Row, 2].Value.ToString();
                        Temp.Column2 = worksheet.Cells[Row, 3].Value;
                        Temp.Column3 = worksheet.Cells[Row, 4].Value;
                        
                     }
                 ColumnList.Add(Temp); 
                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

To creating a SQLite database you need another package (System.Data.SQLite). This code can run in the same class as `readData()` function.

```html
public void createDatabase()
        {
            string databasePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\database.sqlite";

            if (File.Exists(databasePath))
            {
                File.Delete(databasePath);
            }

            // Create database and connection
            var SqlLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + databasePath + ";Version=3;");
            SqlLiteConnection.Open();

            // Create sql lite command
            var SqlLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(SqlLiteConnection);

            // Create table CalibrationMeasurement
            SqlLiteCommand.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE Database(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Column1 TEXT, Column2 INTEGER, Column3 INTEGER)";
            SqlLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            
            int IDCounter = 1;
             for (int i = 0; i < ColumnList.Count; i++)
            { 
            SqlLiteCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Database(ID, Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES(" + IDCounter + ", '" + ColumnList.ElementAt(i).Column1 + "', " + CanList.ElementAt(i).Column2 + ", " + CanList.ElementAt(i).Column3 + ")";
                SqlLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                IDCounter++;
            }
        }
```

Now you only need the click events to read the excel file and create the database.

```html
private void btn_readExcelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            readData();
        }

        private void btn_createDatabaseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            createDatabase();
        }
```

In `XAML` it looks like:

```html
<Button x:Name="btn_readExcel" Click="btn_readExcelClick"/>

<Button x:Name="btn_createDatabase" Click="btn_createDatabaseClick"/>
```